# Не могу отключить Antimalware Service Executable

Tags: ram, службы, диспетчер-задач, regedit

И снова здравствуйте.
На этот раз ошибка такая - не могу отключить Antimalware Service Executable.
В Редакторе Реестра в ветке HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Defender\  есть такой вот файл, называеться он DisableAntiSpyware. Когда я захотел его отключить, изменив значение на 1, выдало вот это -
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Получение такой ошибки может быть связано с тем, что нет необходимых разрешений.

Для того, чтобы их получить необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Нажать ПКМ по пункту реестра, для которого надо получить разрешения.

[image: Разрешения для группы "Windows Defender"]

2. В появившемся окне нажать `Дополнительно`.
3. Далее `Владелец`, выделяем `Администраторов`, `Заменить владельца...` и соглашаемся.

[image: Дополнительные параметры безопасности для "Windows Defender"]

4. В первом окне ставим флажки для `Администраторов`, соглашаемся.

[image: Разрешения для группы...]

После того, как все изменения в реестре будут сделаны, необходимо вернуть системе её права:

1. В окне `Дополнительные параметры...` нажимаем на `Другие пользователи или группы...`, записываем систему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Соглашаемся, также ставим флажок на `Заменить владельца`, и убираем флажки у `Администраторов`.

**P.S.** Все изменения с реестром вы делаете на свой страх и риск!!!

Comment: Я знаю,  но я хочу максимально освободить рам. Этот Antimalware Service Executable жрёт очень много рам на моём устройстве.

Comment: @Anonim, попробуйте этим способом изменить значение пункта реестра `DisableAntiSpyware`, если после перезагрузки `Диспетчер задач` покажет, что процесс `Antimalware Service Executable` не удалось убить, попробуйте переименовать путь к папке Защитника.

Comment: Не могу изменить владельца, не разрешает. Пишет что отказано в доступе